# Get image height after image has loaded

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get image height after image has loaded. The reason for that is chrome gets false height values because it gets height before image has loaded.

```
var imgHeight = $("#pic25").height();
```

Note: I shouldn't use `$(window).load(function(){` on this one.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$("img#pic25").load(function(){
  var height = $(this).height();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to use onload([`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)) event  since load event will be called only after the DOM and associated resources like images got loaded, so it work properly

```
$(body).load(function(){
  var height = $("#pic25").height();
});
```

this would work

to check particular image to be load you can do this like @arvind answers code

Comment: but you should attach this event handler to the "#pic25".. this will only trigger when "body"'s loaded :9

Comment: @Zlatan yah that would be hady if we only need to check only selected image to load not all

Comment: I think you missed quotes around `body`