# Angular.js Dom rendering needs time out to detect element height

Tags: angular, dom, ionic2

In my directive I have the following which usually detects the correct height of the image. However it rarely works without the time out hack. Is there a more reliable way to do this?

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';


    @Directive({
        selector: '[custom-header]', // Attribute selector
    })
    export class CustomHeader {

        header: any;
        headerHeight: any;

        constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {
            // console.log('Hello CustomHeader Directive');
        }


        ngAfterContentInit() {

            var test = this.element.nativeElement;
            setTimeout(function () {
                var content = test.getElementsByClassName('header-image')[0];
                alert(content.clientHeight);
            }, 600);

        }

    }
```

and in the component view (I am using Ionic);

```
<ion-header class="header" custom-header id="header">
    <a  (click)="goToRoot()" ><img class="header-image" src="assets/img/topBar-iPad.png" alt=""/></a>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: where are you using your directive ? HTML markup? update them to the post. on which event your directive will fire?

Comment: What is "'header-image'" and where/how is the image loaded?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you

```
<img class="header-image" src="assets/img/topBar-iPad.png" alt="" 
    #me (load)="headerHeight = me.clientHeight"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i replace the img mark up with that I get a 0 which was the original problem. Maybe it is an ionic thing.

Comment: In normal browser it should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134393/get-image-height-after-image-has-loaded

Comment: It was working better when I used JQuery and wrapping in document ready function. I thought ngOnInit or ngAfterContentInit were equivalent.

Comment: No, they are not equivalent, but the closest you'll get in Angular.

Comment: I still needed to delay the Jquery version too. So there is something weird going on.